# My mask image is a transparent only in Safari

Tags: css, safari, mask

I have an image on my website and with an on scroll animation there's a mask image that gets revealed. The mask itself was a bit transparent in the beginning until I added mask-mode:alpha to the css of the parent of the image (being the div that gets revealed). But apparently mask-mode:alpha doesn't work in Safari.

I tried all the css underneath on each element involved, but still it's a bit transparent in Safari

mask-mode: alpha, -webkit-mask-mode: alpha, -moz-mask-mode: alpha, mask-type: alpha, -webkit-mask-type: alpha, -moz-mask-type: alpha, opacity:1

Any idea why Safari doesn't support this?

Comment: Please include a runnable snippet so we can see the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `mask-mode:alpha` is supported in Safari 15.4 and onwards. https://caniuse.com/?search=mask-mode%3Aalpha

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.